# Работа с контейнером AnchorPane в JavaFX/Scene Builder

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

**Здравствуйте товарищи.**
*Давайте сразу перейду к сути вопроса, у меня стоит цель создать контейнер AnchorPane(Работаю я в SceneBuilder) в который я так же хотел бы поместить тот же контейнер, и строго выровнять его по центре, чтобы при изменений окна он всегда оставался по центру.*

В чем собственно проблема? 
Я не могу понять как это в принципе реализовать, возможно такая идея именно с этим контейнером не возможна, 
а может я тупой, я могу выровнять по центру только в случаи статического окна(стандартно по пикселям), 
но именно в процентном соотношении я не могу указать, 
у меня получается только растягивать этот контейнер по размерам окна.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `VBox` и `HBox`. В первом можно выровнять по вертикали. Во втором по горизонтали.

Comment: Действительно, лучше использовать другие контейнеры, anchorpane заточен на отступы от краев. Если делать через него, то нужно писать привязку отступов к размеру экрана и оно будет пересчитываться при любом изменении, вероятно вызывая подергивания центрального содержимого.

Comment: Ну пересчитывать при любом изменении, это решение уже было у меня в голове, но думал что-то будет другое.

Comment: На счет VBox/HBox проверю, протестирую смогу ли это я реализовать так как хочу, но скорее всего совет отличный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В ситуации разобрался, безусловно при помощи пользователей, но чтобы не стоял вопрос без ответа, я сам объясню до чего я дошел. В общем, методами AnchorPane сделать выравнивание мне не получилось, только растягивать по размерам соответственно окна. Возможно, как сказал пользователь '*Maxim*' решение это пересчитывать при любом изменении окна. Но все же, отличная альтернатива это совокупность ***HBox*** и ***VBox*** (Пользователь '*Tsyklop*'), при помощи которых мы выравниваем ровно по центру нашего окна.